# Android: how can i use just sin or cos instead of Math.sin or Math.cos

Tags: java, android, math

How can i use just sin or cos instead of Math.sin or Math.cos? I tried to import Math.* but I think I need to do something with namespace maybe?.

Comment: You need to `import static java.lang.Math.*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

Import like this. 
This process is called as static import.

Answer (score 0):

Remember they need and Argument in radians so use  Math.toRadians to convert this.

Have a look at

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html